# Ошибка MySQL: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, столкнулся с вот такой ошибкой

> `Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at X:\home\localhost\www\My\profile.php:1) in X:\home\localhost\www\Myprogect\profile.php on line 2`

Как ее можно решить? Вот то, что в profile.php. Заранее спасибо!

```
<?php
session_start();

include("bd.php");

if (!empty($_SESSION['email']) and !empty($_SESSION['password'])) {

    $email    = $_SESSION['email'];
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];
    $result2  = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' ", $db);
    $myrow2   = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
    if (empty($myrow2['id'])) {

        exit("Register plz!");
    }
} else {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'", $db);
    $myrow  = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if (empty($myrow['email'])) {
        exit("no user");
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: [Пользуйтесь поиском](http://hashcode.ru/search/?q=headers+already+sent&t=question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл подключен в другой документ? И если да, проверьте, что подключен он первым, в самом начале документа. В файле profile.php, до **<?php** не дожно быть никакого другого кода, пробелов, пустых строк etc. Проверьте так же, чтоб документ, если он в кодировке **UTF-8**, был сохранен без **BOM**.

Answer (score 1):

Это ошибка PHP, а не Mysql. Функция session_start() посылает заголовок, но если **до нее** был какой-либо вывод (echo, какой-либо текст вне <? ?>, или, как уже сказали - BOM), то заголовки отсылаются до этого вывода и, наталкиваясь на session_start(), php выдает ошибку, что заголовки уже посланы и поезд ушел.
Нужно смотреть то, что описано в ошибке дальше: output started at... и искать вывод именно там.